# How to add node into TreeView Control with Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, treeview

I just wanna learn how to add a node to TreeView control (which takes its data from database with a parent-child relationship). Of course when I select a node the new node I wanna add should be added under the selected one and after adding it into the selected node then I wanna add the new node into database too. I can handle the database part but I don't know how to do the client part.

I hope I could described the problem.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Which TreeView Control are you using?  Is this XUL or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to asp.neting this:
[MVC in the browser](http://blog.codeville.net/2007/08/13/mvc-in-the-browser/)
with js and xslt resolve your (our) problem ;-)